# Understanding Python objects and their variables

Tags: python-3.x, object

I think, I'm seeking help understanding objects and their variables.

```
class Point2d:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
    def xy(self):
        return (self.x, self.y)
p = Point2d()
print("x = ", p.x)
print("y = ", p.y)
p.xy()

p.x = 3
print("x = ", p.x)
print("y = ", p.y)
p.xy()
```

Results:

```
x =  0
y =  0
#Where is the expected (0,0) ??
x =  3
y =  0
(3, 0)
```

My Understanding:
To define a variable for an instance of an object, it should be done in **init** or else all instances share access to the same variable, and **init**  will be run before anything else. I expected to get results when I run p.xy() . Why is it only after editing p.x  can I return p.xy()

I originally was trying:

```
class Point2d:
def __init__(self):
    self.x = 0
    self.y = 0
    self.xy = [self.x, self.y] # Im guesing this wouldn update as the vars update.
```

I suspect I'm illustrating a bunch of misunderstandings. Any help?

Thanks in advance!

Edit In response to comments:
[Colab screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAPRd.png)
Could it be returning (0,0), but covering up that output, and I just happen to see the last return of p.xy() only ?

Comment: "Where is the expected (0,0)" No, there is no expected `(0,0`); the question is where the unexpected final `(3, 0)` came from. `p.xy()` does not `print` so I would expect no output at the end. Are you sure this is your real code?

Comment: I added a screenshot of colab notebook. Maybe the return(0,0) is getting covered up by the folowing print() outputs?

Comment: My guess is that you are looking at a special feature of Colab Notebook where it outputs the value of the last line of the script. If you enter `p.xy()` at the end _twice_, you do not see the output twice. So in the end, what you didn't understand has nothing to do with instances but with `print`. Things do not, as a rule, print themselves by magic; Colab is _adding_ some magic to the last line, that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where is the expected (0,0)

Change

```
p.xy()
```

to

```
print(p.xy())
```